# Vora Tools doesn't recognise columns of table in Modeler

Tags: hana, vora

I created a Vora table (tried both spark-shell with subsequent REGISTER, and Vora Tools SQL editor). I can then see the contents of that table in Data Browser and SQL Editor.

However, when I try to create a new view in a Modeler with that table, I can add the new table as a data source, but there are no columns recognised by Modeler in that table -- see the screenshot. Any idea what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you get any data back when executing `SELECT * FROM DESCRIBE_TABLE(SELECT * FROM FLIGHTS_2008)` in the SQL Editor?

Comment: @reinholdk yes getting all the columns listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows error `Object does not exist` - even though it does exist. I have observed this issue when the table was created with the table name not in uppercase. As a workaround you could drop and recreate the table with uppercase name (in the CREATE TABLE part as well as in the OPTION 'tablename'). It is planned to address this issue in the next Vora version.